# Existence of a minimal element of a set (algebraic curve - proof)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I found the below theorem [here](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) and I am trying to understand the proof. Its actually quite easy to understand but I have one open question:

How it is guaranteed that the minimal element exists?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noetherianness. Algebraic sets correspond to (radical) ideals in an order-reversing manner. In any set of ideals there's a maximal element, so in any set of algebraic sets there's a minimal element.